# How to Deserialize XML with List Items in order

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm deserializing the following `Category` XML that has `Item` child elements as well as `Item_Group` elements that contain `Item` elements.

The issue is that I end up with a list of items in the `Category` and a separate list of items in each item group. I therefore need to add some identifiers so I can preserve the order of the `Item` and `Item_Group` elements within the XML when serializing the XML.

#### XML

```
    <Category Label="CategoryOne" Type="CategoryType">
        <Item Label="Item1" Type="ItemTypeA" Amount="0.00" />
        <Item Label="Item2" Type="ItemTypeB" Amount="0.00" />
        <Item Label="Item3" Type="ItemTypeA" Amount="0.00" />
        <Item_Group Label="ItemGroupOne" Type="ItemGroupType">
            <Item Label="Item4" Type="ItemTypeC" Amount="0.00" />
            <Item Label="Item5" Type="ItemTypeA" Amount="0.00" />
            <Item Label="Item6" Type="ItemTypeB" Amount="0.00" />
        </Item_Group>
        <Item Label="Item7" Type="ItemTypeB" Amount="0.00" />
        <Item Label="Item8" Type="ItemTypeA" Amount="0.00" />
    </Category>
```

Is there something I can add to the following cs proxy to achieve this?

#### CS Proxy for deserializing the XML

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
    public partial class ABCCategory
    {
        private ABCCategoryItem[] itemField;
        private ABCCategoryItemGroup[] itemGroupField;
        private string labelField;
        private string typeField;
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Item")]
        public ABCCategoryItem[] Item
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Item_Group")]
        public ABCCategoryItemGroup[] Item_Group
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemGroupField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemGroupField = value;
            }
        }
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Label
        {
            get
            {
                return this.labelField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.labelField = value;
            }
        }
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.bonafidee.com")]
    public partial class ABCCategoryItemGroup
    {
        private ABCCategoryItem[] itemField;
        private string labelField;
        private string typeField;
        
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Label
        {
            get
            {
                return this.labelField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.labelField = value;
            }
        }
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Item")]
        public ABCCategoryItem[] Item
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.bonafidee.com")]
    public partial class ABCCategoryItem
    {
        private string labelField;
        private string typeField;
        private string amountField;
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Label
        {
            get
            {
                return this.labelField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.labelField = value;
            }
        }
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }
    
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return this.amountField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.amountField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

### EDIT

As requested, below are the cs models that are populated via an http post from a view. The `CategoryModel` then needs to be serialized.

#### cs Models

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Company.Models
{
    public class CategoryModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<ItemGroupModel> ItemGroups { get; set; }
        public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Company.Models
{
    public class ItemGroupModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Company.Models
{
    public class ItemModel
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the object you are trying to serialize ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID please see the updated question including the models. Thanks

Comment: My initial thinking was to add an index attribute to each element within the Category, however this would involve modifying the XML before the application receives it, which I'm not keen to do. Within the view I need to be able to loop through and build html in order for each item or item group. Currently I can only display all the items in the category and then all the item group items so the XML order is not preserved.

Comment: from where do you get this xml ? is it generated when serializing ?

Comment: No it's stored, at the moment in a database and retreived via a database procedure.